# Trying to Install Package that Targets .NETFramework V4.6.1 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget, package

I have seen read how many people have faced this problem. Specifically I'm trying to install the package: `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview` although as the title states it:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView 5.0.1'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

The problem I face is that the two solutions across all the similar posts don't seem to solve the problem for me. I have cleared the Nuget cache, which didn't resolve the issue and the second solution, which states renaming the Package .net folder to the current targeted framework is impossible as I cannot install it at all.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is your project an UWP application. The toolkit targets UWP.

Comment: No I'm creating a WPF project. Out of curiousity why is WPF in the package name if it's meant for UWP?

Comment: Apparently it only supports .Net Framework 4.6.2 or higher. And of course `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls` targets WPF, not UWP.

Comment: Can I change the project framework on the fly or do I need to create an entire new project?

Comment: Just go to the project's Properties page and select another Target framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upgrade the target framework of your project to .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later to be able to consume and use the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView` package.

You do this under Project->Properties->Application->Target Framework in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package targets .NET v4.6.2. You cant install it in a lower framework project.

Simply download the package and open it in 7Zip or any zip extractor to see the package's target framework version. Open \lib\ directory.

[image]